How to setup Xampp for my website project in kali
I have a website project after installing xampp on kali i changed the DocumentRoot statement in the  httpd.conf file  to point to myfile:
DocumentRoot "/home/myname/xampp/htdocs"
Directory "/home/myname/xampp/htocs"
Require all granted

Also i made sure that the xampp/htdocs directories have rwx permissions.
When running localhost in my browser it brings up
indexof/ name/lastmodified ...
Trying to access phpmyadmin it results into
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

How can i solve this error.
I was expecting to see the phpmyadmin page as similar in windows before cloning my project into the htdocs folder.
